# About how to Calculate JVM's memory collect(youngGc+fullGc)?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

```
    package ringBuffer;  

import java.io.BufferedWriter;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.FileWriter;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;  
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;  
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;  
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;  
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode;  

public class PerformanceWriteTest {  
    /** 
     * @param args 
     */  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String outputFile = "F:\\test\\ioTest.txt";  
        Long length = 0L ;   
        Long totalTime = 0L;  

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {  
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();  
                for (Integer i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {  
                    sb.append(j+i.toString() + "V");  
                }  
                sb.append("S");  
                length = (long) sb.toString().length() ;  
                long start =  System.currentTimeMillis() ;  
                appendFileTest(outputFile,sb.toString());  
                totalTime = totalTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) ;  
        }  
        System.out.println(" Total Data is : " + length*5/1000 + " Kbytes! ") ;  
        System.out.println(" Total Time is : " + totalTime) ;  
        System.out.println(" Averge Speed is :" + length*5/(totalTime*1000) + " Kbytes");  
    }  

    private static void appendFileTest(String outputFile, String msgs) {  
//             append1(outputFile, msgs) ;  //FileOutputStream  
//             append2(outputFile, msgs) ;  //FileWriter  
             append3(outputFile, msgs) ;  //RandomAccessFile   
//             append4(outputFile, msgs) ;  //RandomAccessFile   
    }  

    private static void append1(String outputFile, String msgs) {  
        BufferedWriter out = null;     
        try {     
             out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(     
                      new FileOutputStream(outputFile, true)));     
             out.append(msgs) ;  
            } catch (Exception e) {     
                e.printStackTrace();     
            } finally {     
                try {     
                    out.close();     
                } catch (IOException e) {     
                    e.printStackTrace();     
                }     
            }     
    }  

    private static void append2(String outputFile, String msgs) {  
        try {     
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile, true);    
            writer.write(msgs);     
            writer.close();     
        } catch (IOException e) {     
            e.printStackTrace();     
        }     
    }  

    private static void append3(String outputFile, String msgs) {  
          try {     
                RandomAccessFile randomFile = new RandomAccessFile(outputFile, "rw");       
                long fileLength = randomFile.length();      
                randomFile.seek(fileLength);    
                randomFile.writeBytes(msgs);     
                randomFile.close();     
            } catch (IOException e) {     
                e.printStackTrace();     
            }     
    }  

    private static void append4(String outputFile, String msgs) {  
          try {     
                mbb.position(pos) ;  
                mbb.put(msgs.getBytes());  
                pos = pos + msgs.getBytes().length ;  
                raf.close();     
            } catch (IOException e) {     
                e.printStackTrace();     
            }     
    }  

    static RandomAccessFile raf ;  
    static MappedByteBuffer mbb  ;  
    static Integer pos = 0 ;  
}  

use -XX::+PrintGC option, the result is :
[GC 32704K->2928K(124992K), 0.0024320 secs]
[GC 35632K->5200K(124992K), 0.0020096 secs]
[GC 29268K->5200K(124992K), 0.0014802 secs]
[GC 37904K->9792K(157696K), 0.0035590 secs]
[GC 60504K->9840K(157696K), 0.0008594 secs]
[GC 75248K->28224K(224640K), 0.0079131 secs]
[GC 159040K->30572K(224768K), 0.0014706 secs]
[GC 159705K->37516K(355008K), 0.0029869 secs]
[GC 299148K->46668K(355008K), 0.0031385 secs]
[GC 308300K->48980K(511296K), 0.0010842 secs]
[GC 467604K->55860K(511616K), 0.0036752 secs]
```

It can be seen there are 11 times GC,  However, when I use jstat -gcutil pid 
the result is :

```
S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT   
  0.00   0.00  12.01   0.00  11.93      0    0.000     0    0.000    0.000
  0.00   0.00  12.01   0.00  11.93      0    0.000     0    0.000    0.000
  0.00  54.32   5.86   0.01  11.94      1    0.002     0    0.000    0.002
  0.00  54.32   5.86   0.01  11.94      1    0.002     0    0.000    0.002
 96.58   0.00   0.00   0.01  11.94      2    0.004     0    0.000    0.004
 96.58   0.00  21.54   0.01  11.94      2    0.004     0    0.000    0.004
  0.00  96.58   0.00   0.01  11.94      3    0.006     0    0.000    0.006
  0.00  96.58  82.32   0.01  11.94      3    0.006     0    0.000    0.006
 10.57   0.00   0.00  10.61  11.94      4    0.009     0    0.000    0.009
 10.57   0.00   0.00  10.61  11.94      4    0.009     0    0.000    0.009
 10.57   0.00  41.35  10.61  11.94      4    0.009     0    0.000    0.009
 10.57   0.00  41.35  10.61  11.94      4    0.009     0    0.000    0.009
  0.00  11.46  40.92  10.61  11.94      5    0.010     0    0.000    0.010
  0.00  11.46  40.92  10.61  11.94      5    0.010     0    0.000    0.010
  0.00  11.46  40.92  10.61  11.94      5    0.010     0    0.000    0.010
  0.00  11.46  93.70  10.61  11.94      6    0.010     0    0.000    0.010
  8.22   0.00   0.00  31.82  11.94      6    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  8.22   0.00  18.62  31.82  11.94      6    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  8.22   0.00  18.62  31.82  11.94      6    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  8.22   0.00  18.62  31.82  11.94      6    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  8.22   0.00  70.07  31.82  12.06      6    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  8.22   0.00  70.07  31.82  12.06      6    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  8.22   0.00  89.85  31.82  12.07      6    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  8.22   0.00  89.85  31.82  12.07      7    0.018     0    0.000    0.018
  0.00  34.09   0.00  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  0.00  34.09  19.26  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  0.00  34.09  19.26  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  0.00  34.09  53.07  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  0.00  34.09  53.07  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  0.00  34.09  53.07  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  0.00  34.09  79.83  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  0.00  34.09  79.83  32.41  12.07      7    0.020     0    0.000    0.020
  1.98   0.00  10.34  43.02  12.07      8    0.023     0    0.000    0.023
  1.98   0.00  10.34  43.02  12.07      8    0.023     0    0.000    0.023
  1.98   0.00  10.34  43.02  12.07      8    0.023     0    0.000    0.023
  1.98   0.00  23.53  43.02  12.07      8    0.023     0    0.000    0.023
  1.98   0.00  23.53  43.02  12.07      8    0.023     0    0.000    0.023
  1.98   0.00  36.71  43.02  12.07      8    0.023     0    0.000    0.023
```

Only 8 times GC.

My Question is :

1. why the gc times is not the same?
2. use `jstat -gccapacity  pid`, I can get the  `NGCMX :695616.0  OGCMX :1391296.0`
   Then how to calculate the memory collect by the JVM? separately by young Gc and full Gc. 
   Thanks!

Comment: this is the jstat -capacity pid result:                                                  NGCMN    NGCMX     NGC     S0C   S1C       EC      OGCMN      OGCMX       OGC         OC      PGCMN    PGCMX     PGC       PC     YGC    FGC 
      43456.0 695616.0  43456.0 5376.0 5376.0  32704.0    86912.0  1391296.0    86912.0    86912.0  21248.0  83968.0  21248.0  21248.0      0     0

Comment: in case you want to add any info to your post, edit your question and add that info so that it's more likely to be noticed :)

Comment: I think you're getting stats using `jstat -gc pid interval`. What is the interval when you collected the stats ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some understanding of GC logs, hope this info will give you some insight in to what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total time taken by a garbage collector to complete a collection depends on several factors but to name a few

- Type of the Collector being used - ParallelGC, G1GC, CMS etc.
- Region being collected - Young gen or Old gen
- live set in the region at the time of GC - more live objects, more
  time it  takes to mark them
- region size - the bigger the region, the more time it takes to
  compact

In case of YGCT, I can make some guess that as more and more objects are reachable (that's they're marked live), time it takes to mark them and move them to survivor space increases. But to be sure about that we need to get more details about GC. I suggest you add the following flags to get more information about GC.

```
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC 
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -Xloggc:/path-to-logs-dir/gc.log
```

With these flags, you will know more details and hopefully get better insights into the reasons for longer GC pauses.

Using `jstat`, it's not trivial to know the memory collected in each GC. I've executed your code (increasing loop counter to 2Million) and collected `-gc` stats for every one second using this command `jstat -gc 5700 1000` and the results are like below (I removed few columns to make it concise)

```
S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU      YGC    YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
5120.0 5120.0  0.0    0.0   33280.0   2662.6   87552.0      0.0        0    0.000   0      0.000    0.000
5120.0 5120.0  0.0    0.0   33280.0   2662.6   87552.0      0.0        0    0.000   0      0.000    0.000
5120.0 5120.0  0.0    0.0   33280.0   2662.6   87552.0      0.0        0    0.000   0      0.000    0.000
5120.0 5120.0  0.0    0.0   33280.0   2662.6   87552.0      0.0        0    0.000   0      0.000    0.000
3584.0 5120.0  64.0   0.0   265216.0   0.0     102912.0   37158.5      8    0.035   1      0.007    0.043
512.0  4608.0  0.0    0.0   407552.0 48864.8   128000.0   37159.2     10    0.054   3      0.019    0.072
4608.0 4608.0  0.0    0.0   419328.0 263176.3  126464.0   18944.2     11    0.063   4      0.023    0.087
4608.0 4608.0  0.0    0.0   594944.0 475327.6  209920.0   70145.4     12    0.092   5      0.034    0.127
4096.0 4608.0  0.0    32.0  594944.0 384988.3  209920.0   107009.4    13    0.099   5      0.034    0.134
```

As you can see in line 5, in that one second, 8 young gen GCs happened and there's no way to know the young size in each GC just with these stats. Of course, you can reduce the interval to 100ms and if you're lucky you might find the memory but it's not always reliable but using the GC flags I mentioned above, information is always precise.

Following is the GC output with those flags for your program

```
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 33280K [0x00000000d5980000, 0x00000000d8400000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000d5980000,0x00000000d7a00000,0x00000000d7a00000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7f00000,0x00000000d7f00000,0x00000000d8400000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7a00000,0x00000000d7a00000,0x00000000d7f00000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000080c00000, 0x0000000086180000, 0x00000000d5980000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000080c00000,0x0000000080c00000,0x0000000086180000)
 Metaspace       used 2454K, capacity 4494K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 265K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
0.207: [GC (Allocation Failure) 
Desired survivor size 5242880 bytes, new threshold 7 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 33280K->2736K(38400K)] 33280K->2744K(125952K), 0.0178152 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]



Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 2736K [0x00000000d5980000, 0x00000000d8400000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 0% used [0x00000000d5980000,0x00000000d5980000,0x00000000d7a00000)
  from space 5120K, 53% used [0x00000000d7a00000,0x00000000d7cac020,0x00000000d7f00000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7f00000,0x00000000d7f00000,0x00000000d8400000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 8K [0x0000000080c00000, 0x0000000086180000, 0x00000000d5980000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000080c00000,0x0000000080c02000,0x0000000086180000)
 Metaspace       used 2454K, capacity 4494K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 265K, capacity 386K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K
}
```

As its very clear from the above, its only a young gen GC as full GC is 0, before GC

`Young Gen usage is 33MB, Old Gen is 0 MB` after GC
`Young Gen is 2.7MB and Old Gen is 8k`

With that its very clear that after first GC, `~30.5MB` is freed. So GC logs are your best bet and pay attention to them to understand the allocation rates and GC patterns.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Many thanks, I think I know where I was wrong.  I use -gc option and then they are matched, but I still don't know how to calculate the memory collected correctly  from the jstat chart or gc log . I need to find some document for GC. Thanks to  Arkantos Very Much !

Comment: If you're using `PrintHeapAtGC`, then it will print region size before and after collection, the difference is the memory collected.. Isn't that what you need ?

Comment: Thanks very much, but I think that from your gc log , the old gc is 8k,but to the young gc , as we can see: before gc :  total 38400K, used 33280K , after gc: total 38400K, used 2736K  , so I think the memory freed is 33280 -2736=30544~ 30.5MB. I'm trying to calculate from the jstat -gc result, if u set the interval small enough(20ms,et) , u can catch the young gc action every time(from YGC times we can be sure.)! Then u can calculate the gc memory , it just matched  the gc log results . Many thanks! ^_^

Comment: Yup my mistake but like I said having small interval on jstat is not always reliable.. I can only say that you just got lucky and you're able to see them for your allocation rates at the moment. If your application allocates more aggressively, GCs will be very often and even 20ms might not help. Even in those scenarios logs are your best bet :-)

Comment: Yeah, you are right! GC  Logs are best!  but sometimes its not convenient, for example, in a distributed system, like hadoop, if you want to calculate the JVM memory freed by every child JVM, it's hard to use gc logs  to finish that, so I have to use jstat instead, but gc log is really the most precise way!

Comment: Thanks   Arkantos very much ! I finally get  clear about the question!   ^_^

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)